# Big number of the chapter

Tags: chapters, classicthesis

I'm writing my master thesis and I would like to change the number of every chapter with one bigger: I tried to use the package "classicthesis" and it does what I want, but I would change the style (font) of the number, because it's horrible for me.

So I would know how can change this font or (it's better) how I can change the chapter number with one bigger than the default in order to use it in every document class (if it's possible).

You can see my code below:

```
\documentclass[headinclude,footinclude,openany,paper=a4,fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{times}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please add the options you pass to the class and to ClassicThesis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The font used for the chapter number is Euler Roman bold at 70pt, because of the `eulerchapternumbers` option. If you omit it, Palatino would be used.

If you want to use the same typeface as the one used for the chapter title, then you can add to the preamble

```
\renewcommand{\chapterNumber}{%
  \fontsize{70}{70}\usefont{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{b}{n}}
```

Here's a preamble with some changes (I've removed the packages not essential for the example):

```
\documentclass[headinclude,footinclude,openany,paper=a4,fontsize=12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % recommended for languages different from English
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % recommended for inputting accented characters

\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % times is obsolete
\usepackage[scaled=.9]{helvet}   % scaling is recommended

\renewcommand{\chapterNumber}{%
  \fontsize{70}{70}\usefont{\encodingdefault}{\sfdefault}{b}{n}}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Un titolo}
\end{document}
```

Change the number 70 to what suits you best. However, using Times and Helvetica is really like killing the ClassicThesis project and `arsclassica`.

Answer (score 0):

For instance, in order to have a font size of 24pt for the chapter number, with an interlining of 30 pt (~ 20% more than the fontsize), write in your preamble :

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\fontsize{24}{30}\selectfont\arabic{chapter}}
```

To change the font family, you have to use the Karl Berry's names of fonts: to change to Helvetica, say, just use

```
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont.
```

Compiling with XeTeX or LuaLaTeX makes it much simpler, as you can use the usual names of the fonts (e.g. Helvetica). See the `fontspec` package documentation for details.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Redefining `\thechapter` this way isn't good practice because it will also affect, e.g., cross-references.

Comment: It works well, but the code

`\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\fontsize{24}{30}\selectfont\arabic{chapter}}`

changes the fontsize of the sections and subsections, too. I would change only the fontsize of the chapters.